# Ansible loop and print dictionary variable

Tags: ansible

Can anyone help with this basic question?  I have a dictionary variable and I'd like to print it.

```
dict_var:
  - key1: "val1"
  - key2: "val2"  
  - key3: "val3"
```

Is it possible to loop and print its content in a playbook?

Comment: Open a new question if you have other issues e.g. *"build another variable using the values"*. Make it [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: **"*Loop and print variable's content.*"**

A: The variable *dict_var* is a **list**. Loop the list, for example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    dict_var:
      - key1: "val1"
      - key2: "val2"
      - key3: "val3"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ dict_var }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
    "item": {
        "key1": "val1"
    }

    "item": {
        "key2": "val2"
    }

    "item": {
        "key3": "val3"
    }
```

---

Q: **"*Loop and print dictionary.*"**

A: There are more options when the variable is a **dictionary**. For example, use [dict2items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) to *"loop and have key pair values in variables"* *item.key* and *item.value*

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    dict_var:
      key1: "val1"
      key2: "val2"
      key3: "val3"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ dict_var|dict2items }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
    "item": {
        "key": "key1",
        "value": "val1"
    }

    "item": {
        "key": "key2",
        "value": "val2"
    }

    "item": {
        "key": "key3",
        "value": "val3"
    }
```

The next option is to loop the list of the dictionary's keys. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} {{ dict_var[item] }}"
      loop: "{{ dict_var.keys()|list }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
    "msg": "key1 val1"

    "msg": "key2 val2"

    "msg": "key3 val3"
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is printing the dictionary items, you can do:

```
  - debug: msg="{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ dict_var | dict2items }}"
```

Comment: THank you for your message :) 
Basically, print is the first step. Later, I would like to use them and for example build another variable using the values. Would it be possible to loop and have key pair values in a variable ?

Comment: Besides, I get a message when trying your solution: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\n